# extending a libary in my src/

Tags: clojure, namespaces, clojurescript

I'm looking to extend the jayq library (forking on git + leingitdeps isn't an option). How do I go about this?

My project layout looks like this

- project

  - src

    - app
    - jayq

      - core.cljs

where core.cljs should contain my new methods for jayq.core.
my app then tries to load jayq.core (which it does, but without my extra methods)

However this isn't working, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Update:

jayq is included via lein deps.
I'm simply getting that the method doesn't exist in the js console

Comment: could you include your namespace declarations? Do you also have jayq included as a dependency in leiningen?

Answer (score 1):

I have an application called bene-cmp. It compares two reports and spits out the differences. I'm including the following information to denote how things are positioned in my project after having created the project using `lein new bene-cmp`. Hopefully, this will give you something against which you can compare your project layout.

Here is the rough bene-cmp directory structure with pertinent files. Please note that `lein new bene-cmp` created both the directory named `bene-cmp` at the project level and `bene_cmp` in the `src` directory.

```
./bene-cmp/
   project.clj
   .metadata/
   src/
     bene_cmp/
             core.clj
   test/
   lib/
   classes/
```

Here is my project.clj

```
(defproject bene-cmp "1.0.4-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "This is the main benetrak/GIC comparison program."
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]
                 [org.clojure/tools.cli "0.1.0"]
                 [clojure-csv/clojure-csv "1.3.2"]
                 [org.clojure/data.csv "0.1.2"]
                 [bene-csv "1.0.4-SNAPSHOT"]
                 [util "1.0.2-SNAPSHOT"]]

  :omit-source true
  :main bene-cmp.core)
```

core.clj is in `src/bene_cmp`, and its header is as follows:

```
(ns bene-cmp.core
  ^{:author "Charles M. Norton",
    :doc "bene-cmp is the main program to compare two .csv reports.
        Created on March 14, 2012"}
  (:gen-class)
  (:use [clojure.tools.cli])
  (:require [clojure.string :as cstr])
  (:require [bene-csv.core :as bcsv])
  (:require [util.core :as utl])
  (:require [clojure.data.csv :as csv]
            [clojure.java.io :as io])
  (:use clojure-csv.core)
  (:import java.util.Date)
  (:import java.io.File))
```